# Problems with online visitor tracking

Tags: websocket, socket.io, pubnub

I am working with web-socket project. We are tracking the customers of the website and showing that information to our customers dashbaord.

For this we are using pubnub service. They have api to subscribe and her_now to get currenly active connections. But seems it is not working properly. It is not tracking as we expecting.
It is not sending events properly when customers have lot of traffic(>150 active). And even his cost is too high.

We are planning to move to some other technique to do this. Please suggest which one is the good option.

How about nodejs with socket.io. One thing i am thinking the scalability when our customers have lot of traffic.

Please suggest on this.

Thanks,
Govind.

Comment: please email support@pubnub.com asap we have a solution for you but need to chat more to tune your requirements.  Once we have confirmed the fix, we will post the full solution here in this SO/SE forum.

Answer (score 0):

Move to Socket.io (It,s support mobile and all browser) and performance is good

Problems with online visitor tracking:
                 Here is my answer,When user visit you website you emit some event using following code

```
    Server side:
    var io = require('socket.io');
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
//From user
              socket.on('userEnterYourWebsite',function(data){
                              //Do some DB operation means retrive user related information from DB
                             //If emit some data to user 
                              socket.emit('sendToUser',{name:'mmm',state:'tamilnadu'});                      
                  });    
    });

Client Side:
<script>
var socket=io.connect('http://ipaddress:8080');
      var userIDorUniqueID='mmmmmmm';
       socket.emit('userEnterYourWebsite',{uniqueID:userIDorUniqueID});

           //From server
           socket.on('sendToUser',function(data){
                          console.log(data.state);
                        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Property Annouce Max

You just need to [set the Presence Announce Max property on the Presence add-on higher](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/54/using-presence-got-a-high-occupancy-channel-then-mind-your-presence-announce-max-property). Contact support@pubnub.com to set it higher than 100.

## Build vs. Buy

What will be the cost of scaling your DIY node/socket.io solution? See the following before considering the DIY route.

- http://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-vs-buy-why-diy-isnt-always-better/
- http://www.pubnub.com/customers/swaplingo/
- http://www.pubnub.com/customers/tint/